# Firebase payload json for cross platforms are not working

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase to send message across iOS & Android devices. I follow the document of google but it's still not working.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

In the document, they gave an example

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Match update",
       "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
     },
     "android":{
       "ttl":"86400s",
       "notification"{
         "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
       }
     },
     "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "5",
       },
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
         }
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "TTL":"86400"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

and I replaced some placeholders of this example with my Firebase configurations then I ran Postman and it returned 400 bad Request

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"dRnhMNngY02mofqQ-5no8K:APA91bEcaaZ3QBWTdZfN3hU1tJzy6_ChW4FMArXbbWvT-8wq11TDN2jLy7uaT-Wzjq_xAzPqZfVje5_n54pVLnCfUUPTp_EuS3CykGnysHO0BeJn0TEgP-czc_y2kdyVMW-39mlSh8-t",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Match update",
       "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
     },
     "android":{
       "ttl":"86400s",
       "notification": {
         "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
       }
     },
     "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "5"
       },
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
         }
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "TTL":"86400"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

But when I changed it. Set **to** & **notification** to the first level of json. My iOS device displayed a notification.

```
{
  "to": "dRnhMNngY02mofqQ-5no8K:APA91bEcaaZ3QBWTdZfN3hU1tJzy6_ChW4FMArXbbWvT-8wq11TDN2jLy7uaT-Wzjq_xAzPqZfVje5_n54pVLnCfUUPTp_EuS3CykGnysHO0BeJn0TEgP-czc_y2kdyVMW-39mlSh8-t",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Match update",
    "body": "Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
  }"message": {
    "token": "dRnhMNngY02mofqQ-5no8K:APA91bEcaaZ3QBWTdZfN3hU1tJzy6_ChW4FMArXbbWvT-8wq11TDN2jLy7uaT-Wzjq_xAzPqZfVje5_n54pVLnCfUUPTp_EuS3CykGnysHO0BeJn0TEgP-czc_y2kdyVMW-39mlSh8-t",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Match update",
      "body": "Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
    },
    "android": {
      "ttl": "86400s",
      "notification": {
        "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
      }
    },
    "apns": {
      "headers": {
        "apns-priority": "5"
      },
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
        }
      }
    },
    "webpush": {
      "headers": {
        "TTL": "86400"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why the example of Firebase from Google is not working? Moreover, I tried to send to my Android device, it said "InvalidRegistration" message but when I tested sending message in https://console.firebase.google.com -> Cloud Messaging -> Compose notification. I pasted the same token that I used to test Android and it worked...

Really confused?!

I found several articles and test but it did work for me. I just want to have a structure of json file to work for both iOS and Android (also need to send both type of message as: notification & data)

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thank you a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Just want to up this question and not to be missed